# How to delete Junit3 support in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, oomph

I am using a freshly downloaded eclipse (eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64) from eclipse.org.
When I create a new JUnit Test Case using the wizard, then the wizard allows to add a "New JUnit 3 test".

[image]

Additionally when I am inside my test class and want to add a new test method via writing test and hitting Ctrl+Space then the template shown above is "test3".

How can I remove JUnit 3 support completely from my eclipse?
Or even better, since we also use a pre-configured eclipse installed via the eclipse-installer (oomph), how can I avoid to install it in the first place? Our oomph installation is based on package epp.package.jee.

Answer (score 0):

Use eclipse-jee-oxygen-M2-win32-x86_64 from eclipse.org.
You can download it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/M2/eclipse-jee-oxygen-M2-win32-x86_64.zip

When you will create a new Junit Test Case using the wizard. It will not add Junit 3 support instead It will add Junit 4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a pity, but this does not solve my problem: The version you provided is just a milestone build and older than the one I downloaded. Moreover this version allows me to select JUnit3 in the New TestCase Wizard and even the test3 template is available.

Comment: @baumato Yes this version allows you to select Junit.

Comment: Yes, but I want to remove JUnit3 support completely, if that is possible.